At what point during system boot is BIOS loaded
On a traditional x86 system boot from power on, at what point does the BIOS get loaded?
A CPU will progress from power off to S5 sleep state, through to S0 operational state. Is there a standard stage where the BIOS gets loaded?

What do you mean by "loaded"?  The usual meaning is "load into memory", but on a traditional x86 system the BIOS is in ROM and there's nothing to load because it's already there.

Normally the BIOS ROM is mapped so that it covers the CPU's reset address, so the very first instruction executed by the CPU is from the BIOS.  Whatever happens prior to that is internal hardware details.

By loaded I mean having that reset address read and the firmware in the ROM execute. Specifically I trying to understand which power state the BIOS is first accessed during
